# Java enum: get FieldName knowing its value

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Code {

    E1330("MERCOSUR (SOUTH AMERICAN COMMON MARKET)"),
    E0257("Guinea Biss."),
    E0252("Gambia");

private Code(String value){
   setStringValue(value);
}   
private Code (int value) {
    setIntValue(value);
}

private int intValue;
private String stringValue;

public String getStringValue() {
    return stringValue;
}
public int getIntValue() {
    return intValue;
}

public void setStringValue(String value) {
    this.stringValue = value;
}
public void setIntValue(int value) {
    this.intValue = value;
}
}
```

How can I get the field name of the Code whose value is "Gambia"?
-> it would be E0252

Thank you

Comment: is this a valid decl? got error when copied / pasted your code

Comment: Add a reverse `HashTable<String,String> rTable = new ..;` then add in Constructor `rTAble.put(value, this.name());` - give method to get from `rTable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search for it via a loop:

```
String val = "Gambia";
String field = "";

for (Code c : Code.values())
    if (c.getStringValue().equals(val)) {
        field = c.name();
        break;
    }

System.out.println(field);
```

Output:

> E0252